# Select greatest duplicate and unique row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
id  | header            | cat   | newsfeed  | user      | hide  | update
1   | header12345678    | Manga | news1     | william   | 0     | 0
3   | header12345679    | Manga | news2     | william   | 0     | 1
4   | header12345610    | Manga | news3     | william   | 0     | 1
5   | 12345             | Manga | news4     | william   | 0     | 0
6   | 12346             | Manga | news5     | william   | 0     | 0
7   | 12347             | Manga | news6     | william   | 0     | 6
```

I want to select the greatest `id` of the duplicate `update`, and if there isn't any duplicates, then just select the only one that isn't a duplicate.

The thing is, i have set it up, so that the original row, has `update=0` and when `update` isn't 0, it is equal to the id of the original row.

So i want the result of the SQL-statement to be that:

```
id  | header            | cat   | newsfeed  | user      | hide  | update
4   | header12345610    | Manga | news3     | william   | 0     | 1
5   | 12345             | Manga | news4     | william   | 0     | 0
7   | 12347             | Manga | news6     | william   | 0     | 6
```

Because `id=4` has the greatest id of the duplicates, `id=5` has no duplicates and `id=7` has the greatest id of the duplicates.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM newsfeed sr1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM  newsfeed sr2
    WHERE sr1.update = sr2.update AND
          sr1.id < sr2.id AND
          sr2.id > 0
)
```

Didn't work as well as i thought.

Comment: Can you say, how you are consider these are duplicate

Comment: @VigneshKumar It is determined by the `update` column. When `update != 0` then it is a duplicate of the row with `id = update`

Comment: `id=1, id=3, id=4` is duplicates, because both `id=3` and  `id=4`'s `update` reffer to `id=1`. Hope you get it

Comment: You said Id id=7 has the greatest id of the duplicates know. how id = 7 is duplicate from id = 6

Comment: `id=7` is duplicate of `id=6` because `id=7`'s `update` reffer to `id=6`. Basically: what @hage said

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i use MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query my friend:

```
select * from newsfeed where id in
(select max(id) from
(select id,
case when update = 0 then id else update end update1
from newsfeed)t1
group by update1);
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58265/6)

Comment: That did it, and WAY easier than i thought! Thanks!

Comment: @Hamidreza Hmm, this gives me rows with IDs `4,6, and 7` . But it should be `4,5,7`, shouldn't it? `6` is not in the result because `7` is "newer"...

Comment: I'm so sorry my friend, my answer was wrong ,but i edit it and it works fine now.

Comment: Yea, i noticed my site wasn't working as i wanted, so i decided to go back to the answer, and find an updated one xD Thanks, lol